# JPA Class field caching support

Tags: hibernate, entity, jpa

I have the following class field

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region="blProducts")
@JoinColumn(name = "DEFAULT_SKU_ID")
protected Sku defaultSku;
```

I want to get rid of @Cache annotation from hibernate. Is this possible i can replace it some other persistence annotations.